# JS : Get clipboard data on Click (not on Paste)

Tags: javascript, onclick, clipboard, clipboarddata

How can I get the clipboard data on click on a button.. not on pasting into textarea.

Something like this :

```
<button onclick="seeClipBoard">Click to see your clipboard data</button>

<div id="seeData"></div>

var seeClipBoard = function() {
    var data = ****************** ;
    $("#seeData").html(data);
};
```

I d'ont want to use the paste event, but a click

Thank you!

Comment: How is this a duplicate? He clearly said "click", not "paste". The question linked to does not address user3134277's question.